# Correct way to remove object from @ManyToMany list

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

I created relation @ManyToMany with the same entity.

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

...

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "table_friends", joinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "userId"), inverseJoinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "friendId"))
private List<User> friends;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "table_friends", joinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "friendId"), inverseJoinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "userId"))
private List<User> friendsof;
```

I created a few "users" and added them to friend list:

```
User u1 = new User();
User u2 = new User();
User u3 = new User();

u1.getFriends().add(u2);
u1.getFriendsof().add(u2);
u1.getFriends().add(u3);
u1.getFriendsof().add(u3);
```

When I remove a friend from the list `u1.getFriends().remove(u3)`, everything is ok . But when I want to delete the user from the database `u3.remove()`, friends of u1 still are the same, although already in the database list of friend is correct.

1. Can I somehow refresh the list after removing a user?
2. And if so, how can I know which list of friend I need to refresh?

Edit: Also seems to me that I should remove the (cascade = CascadeType.ALL), because when I remove u1, removes all paired members. Is this the correct behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, why do you need 2 list `friends` and `friendsOf`? If you're my friend, isn't it obvious that I am your friend?

Besides, if you only want to end the relationship between 2 `User`, you should use `u1.getFriends().remove(u3)`.

Lastly, if you want to remove a user. You should create an `EntityManager em` and execute the command `em.remove(u3)`. This command will delete u3 as well as the relationship. However, you should be careful with `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`. This cascadeType means that if you remove u3, u1 will also be removed. I think you should leave it `@ManyToMany` without cascade.

Comment: All cascade I have already removed. When it comes to remove, I use the EntityManager em.remove(u). But it doesn't work as I expected because after em.remove(u3), when I check in database (by MySQL Administrator), u3 doesn't exist, however it still exist in u1.friends. Disappears after restart program. Any idea why so late?

Comment: hmmm it's weird. I tried to remove an entry in my app and all relationships are updated properly. ^^ I think you should update your question with this weird behavior. I'm sure someone else will be able to help you with it

Comment: I did like what I told you. I called `em.remove('someEntity')`.

Comment: If you invoke `em.refresh(-)`, will it properly reflect new friends list?

Comment: I can't invoke em.remove or em.refresh directly in the same place where I created Users. User Entity extends BaseEntity which has refresh and remove public method. Maybe that's the problem. After refresh nothing changed :(

Comment: hmm I think you should not use `EntityManager` inside an `Entity`. Usually, you will inject an `EntityManager` into an Enterprise JavaBean and you will use the bean to persist entities.

Comment: Honestly I never used the EJB. Can I somehow create it quickly or do without it.

Comment: In my opinon, you should know about EJB. It will help you achieve MVC architecture which is very popular with JavaEE. Take a quick look at the code at the top of this [page](http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/dynamic-datasource-routing/README.html). It's very easy to inject EntityManger into an EJB.

Comment: I checked, and in Netbeans in desktopApplictation I can't create EJB. Of course I can do it manual but I think its not the corrct approach.

Comment: oh your application seems to be a small one. Hmm even so, I think your desktop application still have some class which would listen to request. For example, if the user clicks New, something must be there to wait for that request and act on it. I think you can try injecting the EntityManager into that thing :P

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution but only when we using EclipseLink.

In persistance.xml you need to add property:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

Then everything works fine.